# multiple web api routes not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

I am building a custom module for DNN 8.

I have built modules with multiple routes declared in a controller class.  For some reason with this particular controller class, any module routes declared after the first one just returns the following error:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI No action was
>   found on the controller 'ServiceName' that matches the request.

If I change the order of my routes, the first one declared works, but all the following ones do not.

This controller class is VERY simple.  Here it is:

```
    Public Class BranchServiceController
    Inherits DnnApiController
    Implements IServiceRouteMapper

    ''REGISTER SERIVCE ROUTES / URL
    Const moduleName As String = "ModuleName"

    Public Sub RegisterRoutes(routeManager As IMapRoute) Implements IServiceRouteMapper.RegisterRoutes

        routeManager.MapHttpRoute(moduleName,
                                  "branches",
                                  "{controller}/{action}/{DepID}",
                                  New String(){"ModuleName.Services.Controllers"})

        routeManager.MapHttpRoute(moduleName,
                                  "locations",
                                  "{controller}/{action}/{BranchID}",
                                  New String() {"ModuleName.Services.Controllers"})

    End Sub

    <HttpGet>
    <ActionName("locations")>
    <AllowAnonymous>
    Public Function GetLocation(BranchID As Int32) As List(Of BranchLocation)
        Try

            Dim locationCtl As New BranchLocationController

            ''get Branch based on supplied id
            Dim lBranch As List(Of BranchLocation) = locationCtl.GetBranchLocations(BranchID)

            Return lBranch

        Catch ex As Exception
            LogException(ex)
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function

    <HttpGet>
    <ActionName("branches")>
    <AllowAnonymous>
    Public Function GetBranch(DepID As Int32) As List(Of Branch)
        Try

            Dim branchCtl As New BranchController

            ''get Branch based on supplied id
            Dim lBranch As List(Of Branch) = branchCtl.GetBranchs(DepID)

            Return lBranch

        Catch ex As Exception
            LogException(ex)
            Return Nothing
        End Try

    End Function

End Class
```

if the branches route is first then it works, if the locations route is declared first it works.  All I am doing is copying and pasting to change the order so I know the routes are accurate.

I have never come across this before.

**WHAT I TRIED:**

So I broke each of these routes out into their own class.  Now the same problem occurs.  I was able to add multiple routes to other controller classes in my project.  There is something about these two routes that are conflicting.

I can see in the log4net file that the routes are declared separately and correctly

```
2016-04-07 22:20:32,595 [][Thread:37][TRACE] DotNetNuke.Web.Api.Internal.ServicesRoutingManager - Mapping route: moduleName-locations-0 @ DesktopModules/moduleName/API/{controller}/{action}/{BranchID}
2016-04-07 22:20:32,598 [][Thread:37][TRACE] DotNetNuke.Web.Api.Internal.ServicesRoutingManager - Mapping route: moduleName-branches-0 @ DesktopModules/moduleName/API/{controller}/{action}/{DepID}
```

what is weird is if I comment out the routeManager.MapHttpRoute for the locations route in the separate class, the branches route will work.

### Question

Can someone help me figure out why this branches route won't work when the locations route is created?

---

### EDIT 1:

What I have tried:

1. I thought that maybe there was an issue because my action name
   matched the  name of hte peta poco class the object is
   defined in.  So I changed the action name to something random and
   that DID NOT fix it.
2. I thought maybe there was an issue with
   multiple routes following the same pattern as
   {controller}/{action}/{DepID} so I made sure that all routes had a
   different ending parameter name - DID NOT FIX
3. I made sure the parameter names of the route and function matched - this was not the issue
4. I moved every route into its own Controller class so each route has a different controller portion of the uri.  DID NOT FIX

Further detail, I have one route that always works - and then four that do not.  Of those 4, the first route that is defined works, but the following three do not.  I have a log4net log that logs the route creation:

```
2016-04-08 11:31:35,358  - Mapping route: KrisisShifts-locations-0 @ DesktopModules/KrisisShifts/API/{controller}/{action}/{BranchID}
2016-04-08 11:31:35,363  - Mapping route: KrisisShifts-branches-0 @ DesktopModules/KrisisShifts/API/{controller}/{action}/{DepartmentID}
2016-04-08 11:31:35,369  - Mapping route: KrisisShifts-ranks-0 @ DesktopModules/KrisisShifts/API/{controller}/{action}/{ID}
2016-04-08 11:31:35,373  - Mapping route: KrisisShifts-GetMonthCal-0 @ DesktopModules/KrisisShifts/API/{controller}/{action}/{CalID}/{DepID}/{MonthID}/{iYear}
2016-04-08 11:31:35,378  - Mapping route: KrisisShifts-department-0 @ DesktopModules/KrisisShifts/API/{controller}/{action}/{portalID}
2016-04-08 11:31:35,402  - Registered a total of 14 routes
```

The GetMonthCal route works without error every time.  Locations returns a result while the remaining 3 (*branches, ranks, department*) all return the ***no action found ...*** error

If I comment out **locations**, then **branches** will work but the remaining two will not.  If i comment out **locations** and **branches** then **ranks** work but not the last one.

Here are the route declarations from each class:

```
        routeManager.MapHttpRoute(moduleName, "branches", "{controller}/{action}/{DepartmentID}", New String() {"Krisis.Modules.KrisisShifts.Services.Controllers"})
        routeManager.MapHttpRoute(moduleName, "GetMonthCal", "{controller}/{action}/{CalID}/{DepID}/{MonthID}/{iYear}", New String() {"Krisis.Modules.KrisisShifts.Services.Controllers"})
        routeManager.MapHttpRoute(moduleName, "department", "{controller}/{action}/{portalID}", New String() {"Krisis.Modules.KrisisShifts.Services.Controllers"})
        routeManager.MapHttpRoute(moduleName, "locations", "{controller}/{action}/{BranchID}", New String() {"Krisis.Modules.KrisisShifts.Services.Controllers"})
        routeManager.MapHttpRoute(moduleName, "ranks", "{controller}/{action}/{ID}", New String() {"Krisis.Modules.KrisisShifts.Services.Controllers"})
```

I know that the route structure is working because I get results

There is obviously some kind of conflict going on here that I can not find.  The controller is getting hit because the routes are created, but the action can not be found for some reason.

Comment: What happens if you rename your parameters as `ID` and just map a single route `{controller}/{action}/{ID}`?

Comment: @strickt01 that did not work.  I'm still fighting with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reasoning behind this is that your routes are actuall all the same when it comes to pattern matching.

Yes, you out a different name at the end. But if you look at the URL that would be used. You get something similar to the following abbreviated URL

Controller/Action/My-branch
Or
Controller/Action/My-Department

There is no way that the routing system would know that the top one is a branch and that the bottom one is a department.

The typical recommendation is to keep with just an id parameter. Otherwise you will need to change the signature. Possibly something like

{controller}/{action}/b/{branchName}

That would differentiate the route. Then you could replace the /b with /d for department.

Comment: thanks for the explanation Mitchel, I thought that the different action method name would be used in the differentiation, but I guess not.  adding the "d" or "b" or something similar will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Basically DNN route is almost same like Asp.MVC route.
So if you want to specific your controller, you can make it static like this :

```
mapRouteManager.MapHttpRoute(
                moduleFolderName: "moduleFolder",
                routeName: "blablabla",
                url: "branches/{DepID}",
                defaults: new { controller = "BranchService", action = "GetBranch", DepID = RouteParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new[] { "MyNamespace" }
            );
```

And from the Url, I can just call it :
http://../DesktopModules/moduleFolder/API/branches/1